# Parallels ignoring added registry DWORD values?

Tags: active-directory, virtualization, mac-osx, samba

I'm attempting to join a Win7 Pro machine running on lion through Parallels 7 to

Parallels is set to use briged ethernet adapter, DNS has been set to our internal servers, can ping the domain controller by IP and hostname. Gateway & Subnet are correct. I've applied the registry edits win7 needs to connect to samba shares:

```
HKLM\System\CCS\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
        DWORD  DomainCompatibilityMode = 1
        DWORD  DNSNameResolutionRequired = 0
```

Am I overlooking something?

4/19 I think I may have isolated the issue. Checking the Windows NetSetup log, it appears that the registry tweaks required to join a win7 machine to our Samba Domain Controller are not sticking, despite being correctly set to the values above in the registry editor. The values for DomainCompatabilityMode & DNSNameResolutionRequired are defaulting to incorrect values, which I am thinking is preventing the join.

```
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpDoDomainJoin
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpMachineValidToJoin: 'LOADMACHINE'
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685     OS Version: 6.1
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685     Build number: 7601 (7601.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850)
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685     ServicePack: Service Pack 1
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685     SKU: Windows 7 Professional
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpDomainJoinLicensingCheck: ulLicenseValue=1, Status: 0x0
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpGetLsaPrimaryDomain: status: 0x0
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpMachineValidToJoin: status: 0x0
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpJoinDomain
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685     Machine: LOADMACHINE3CB3
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685     Domain: DOMAINNAME
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685     MachineAccountOU: (NULL)
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685     Account: DOMAINNAME\root
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685     Options: 0x27
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpLoadParameters: loading registry parameters...
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpLoadParameters: DNSNameResolutionRequired not found, defaulting to '1' 0x2
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpLoadParameters: DomainCompatibilityMode not found, defaulting to '0' 0x2
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpLoadParameters: status: 0x2
04/19/2012 11:25:31:685 NetpValidateName: checking to see if 'DOMAINNAME' is valid as type 3 name
04/19/2012 11:25:31:794 NetpCheckDomainNameIsValid [ Exists ] for 'DOMAINNAME' returned 0x0
04/19/2012 11:25:31:794 NetpValidateName: name 'DOMAINNAME' is valid for type 3
04/19/2012 11:25:31:794 NetpDsGetDcName: trying to find DC in domain 'DOMAINNAME', flags: 0x40001010
04/19/2012 11:25:31:794 NetpDsGetDcName: failed to find a DC in the specified domain: 0x54b, last error is 0x0
04/19/2012 11:25:31:794 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: NetpDsGetDcName returned: 0x54b
04/19/2012 11:25:31:794 NetpJoinDomainOnDs: Function exits with status of: 0x54b
04/19/2012 11:25:31:794 NetpDoDomainJoin: status: 0x54b
```

Viewing these values (DomainCompatibilityMode & DNSNameResolutionRequired) in regedit clearly shows that they are set to the appropriate values of:
    DomainCompatibilityMode=1
    DNSNameResolutionRequired=0

Now I am left wondering why NetpLoadParameters is not 'seeing' these added values, and defaulting to the incorrect ones.

Comment: How about telling us what the error message is when you try to going the domain?  Have you done a tcpdump on OSX and watched the join attempt?  Do you see any failures?

Comment: I think the issue actually has to do with the parallel'd windows registry somehow not properly saving added DWORD values. I've updated my original post. @Zoredache

Comment: What version of Samba are you using?

Comment: Also, there is apparently a patch for Win 7 machines failing to join Samba domains. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2171571

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the Hotfix @JohnThePro! Unfortunately, trying to run the Standalone update package on the win 7 virtual machine results in "The update is not applicable to your computer". Looking for a workaround now.

Comment: If you're on SP1, I believe it's already incorporated. Have you made sure to allow Parallel's to do whatever it needs through the OSX firewall? I'm not worried about the VM being able to add to the domain, it more kinda sounds like either a)you need a newer version of Samba, or b)the host machine's firewall is blocking the VM in some way.

Comment: Yeah, it appears the hotfix is already applied through windows update. There is nothing blocking the connection on the Mac, and my tcpdump looks good. We're running the latest samba release 3.6.4, everything else is playing nice with the DC which has me thinking it's a VM issue. Appreciate the advice @JohnThePro

Comment: Just to make sure, had you looked at this? http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Windows7#Samba_versions_supporting_Windows7_Domain_Logon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dcdiag is for running on the DC in troubleshooting a malfunctioning DC. If everything else on the domain works then I would assume it's your win7 machine that's the issue.

How far to you get in the domain join process and what is the error?  Do you get prompted to log in or does it tell you can't find domain?

Not sure what lanman settings for samba shares has to do with a Windows AD DC.

Comment: The registry additions are required by Win 7 machines in order to properly work with our Samba Domain Controller. The error message I'm encountering is generic "Specified Domain either does not exist or could not be contacted." I will post a TCP dump from OSX when I get a chance. @bret

Comment: lol, yea that key piece of info you didn't mention was "samba".